# Ckeditor 3.7.1 + Paperclip (Absolute Paths in Email)

Tags: paperclip, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-3.2, email-attachments, image-upload

I have installed the ckeditor 3.7.1 and Paperclip gems (gem 'ckeditor', '3.7.1' gem 'paperclip') in Rails 3.2.3 by following the instructions posted on github (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor). It all seems to be working except that when I try to send an email with AccountMailer using the html (which contains uploaded images) generated from the ckeditor it gives me this:

```
<img alt=3D"logo" src=3D"/assets/logo= .png" />
```

when I want this:

```
<img alt=3D"logo" src=3D"www.mydomain.com/assets/logo= .png" />
```

I've found the documentation very confusing and the gem does not provide access to config.js in order to modify baseHref. I've tried changing the attachment_file.rb and picture.rb in model/ckeditor so that the url includes the domain but this breaks the uploading capability. I've also tried ckeditor_rails but this removes uploading capability and I do not have time
to create custom browsers and uploaders.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up replacing them all before sending the email.
`while !the_html.sub!(/\"\/ckeditor_assets\//, "\"#{DOMAIN_NAME}/ckeditor_assets/").nil? do end`

I am still curious about a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Add the function in your Ckeditor::Picture Model**

```
  def url_content
    if Rails.env.production?
        host_url="http://your_domen"
     else
        host_url="http://localhost:3000"
     end
    host_url+url(:content)
  end
```